# FullText Index InnoDB Double Quote search -- Memory Exhaustion

Tags: mysql

I have a table with approximately 4 million rows. The DB Engine is InnoDB.

One of the columns is a **Full-Text** Index.

when I do a **match(X) against ('Y')**... I get the results.

when I do a **match(X) against ('"Y"')**... the memory gets exhausted and I get an error

**``ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query''**

the reason for using double quotes in my against phrase is that I actually have a do a match against two consecutive words, .e.g., against('"food chain"').

I tried fiddling with the **max_allowed_packet** with different values in the increasing order, but no luck.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Regards,

tu.

PS: I have also asked this question on MySQL DEV Forum

Comment: You should be able to use single quotes to enclose any string literal

Comment: I need to match the exact string "YYY ZZZ", doing 'YYY ZZZ' matches all the records with YYY or ZZZ, I have to match "YYY ZZZ" together.